# Laravel eloquent with() nested relationship fields in parent unnested

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

the elequent query i have is:

```
$rows = ProjectLogin::with(
    'User:PRIVATE,naam', 
    'Project:PRIVATE,naam', 
    'Queue:PRIVATE,queue_naam', 
    'AgentStatus:PRIVATE,status'
)
->limit(10)->get();
```

this will return this array if i do $rows->toArray():

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▶]
  1 => array:18 [▼
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => "PRIVATE"
    "PRIVATE" => "PRIVATE"
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "user" => array:2 [▼
      "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
      "naam" => "SOME NAME"
    ]
    "project" => array:2 [▼
      "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
      "naam" => "SOME PROJECT NAME"
    ]
    "queue" => null
    "agent_status" => array:2 [▼
      "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
      "status" => "SOME STATUS"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:18 [▶]
  3 => array:18 [▶]
  4 => array:18 [▶]
  5 => array:18 [▶]
  6 => array:18 [▶]
  7 => array:18 [▶]
  8 => array:18 [▶]
  9 => array:18 [▶]
]
```

the withs are in a array, but i dont want nested arrays, plus it contains the foreign keys which i dont need.

i want the array to look like for example:

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▶]
  1 => array:18 [▼
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => "PRIVATE"
    "PRIVATE" => "PRIVATE"
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "PRIVATE" => PRIVATE
    "user_naam" => 'SOME NAME'
    "project_naam" => 'SOME NAME'
    "agent_status_status" => 'SOME STATUS'
    
  ]
  2 => array:18 [▶]
  3 => array:18 [▶]
  4 => array:18 [▶]
  5 => array:18 [▶]
  6 => array:18 [▶]
  7 => array:18 [▶]
  8 => array:18 [▶]
  9 => array:18 [▶]
]
```

**How can i get specifics columns from a query that uses with() in the main array instead of nested arrays?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i found 2 solutions to my issue.**

the first solution is accepting relations are nested and making sure they return default fields with the "withDefault()" method. which would look like:

```
$rows = ProjectLogin::
with([
    'User' => function($query) { 
        $query->select('PRIVATE','naam')
        ->withDefault(['PRIVATE' => '','naam' => '']); 
    },
    'Project' => function($query) { 
        $query->select('PRIVATE','naam')
        ->withDefault(['PRIVATE' => '','naam' => '']); 
    },
    'Queue' => function($query) { 
        $query->select('PRIVATE','queue_naam')
        ->withDefault(['PRIVATE' => '','queue_naam' => '']); 
    },
    'AgentStatus' => function($query) { 
        $query->select('PRIVATE','status','status_colour')
        ->withDefault(['PRIVATE' => '','status' => '','status_colour' => '']); 
    },
]
)->get();
```

the other solution is if nested array are not a option is using "map()" which  would look like:

```
$rows = ProjectLogin::with(
    'User:PRIVATE,naam', 
    'Project:PRIVATE,naam', 
    'Queue:PRIVATE,queue_naam', 
    'AgentStatus:PRIVATE,status,status_colour'
)
->get()
        ->map(function($item) {
            $item = $item->toArray();
            return [
            'PRIVATE' => $item['PRIVATE'],
            'PRIVATE' => $item['PRIVATE'],
            'PRIVATE' => $item['PRIVATE'],
            'PRIVATE' => $item['PRIVATE'],
            'user_name' => @$item['user']['naam'],
            'project_name' => @$item['project']['naam'],
            'queue_name' => @$item['queue']['queue_naam'],
            'status' => @$item['agent_status']['status'],
            'PRIVATE' => $item['PRIVATE'],
            'status_colour' => @$item['agent_status']['status_colour'],
            ];
        });
```

the `$item = $item->toArray();` is important, otherwise it will create new queries that make n+1 obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "How can i get specifics columns from a query that uses with()?"

Try writing `with()`  with a callback function like this:

```
$rows = ProjectLogin::with( 'User:PRIVATE,naam', function($query){
    $query->select('column_name');
})
->with( 'Project:PRIVATE,naam', function($query){
    $query->select('column_name');
})
->with( 'Queue:PRIVATE,queue_naam', function($query){
    $query->select('column_name');
})
-> with( 'AgentStatus:PRIVATE,status', function($query){
    $query->select('column_name');
})
```

Notice how i separated the `with()` into different lines, this is because when you pass a callback function to the function it can only take one parameter.

On the issue of the array format, I'm not sure this will work, but try putting them into a collection and flatten that collection to give you the desired state.

```
$flattened = $collection->flaten()
```

The variable `$collection` holding your eloquent collection results.

Comment: Instead of multiple `->with()` clauses, use `->with()` with an array: `->with(['User:PRIVATE,naam' => function ($query){ ... }), 'Project:PRIVATE,naam' => function ($query) { ... }, ...])`. That was the main mistake in the query. This _works_, but is horrendous to look at (in my experience anyway)

Comment: this is not the solution. you cant use User:PRIVATE,naam in a with if you use a callback, it errors. you also need to mention the foreign key in the select. so my code looks like this, but it return the same back as how it had it previous without the callback. the relations are in seprate arrays in the array:                                                         
`$rows = ProjectLogin::`
        `with(['User' => function($query)`
        `{`
            `$query->select('PRIVATE','naam AS user_name');`
        `}])`
        `->limit(10)->get();`

Comment: thats partly my fault, i updated my main question to my specific need:                                    **How can i get specifics columns from a query that uses with() in the main array instead of nested arrays?**